# How to set col_width when send smtp mail with datafram.to_html in the content

Tags: python, html, smtp

I want to send a dataframe by smtp, used df.to_html, but the col-width not under control.
the param 'col-space' dose not work whether pass int or str or list to it.

```
      content = df_mail.to_html(col_space=[20,20,20,20,20,20,500,20,50,20,500],index=False, border=5, justify='left',na_rep=" ")
```

if i remove the last col(url in it), it becomes much more better.

So i wonder how can i narrow the last col, and widen someone col else.thank you for your kindly advise.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook will change `col_width` when displaying e-mail to keep the website link column with `max-`width, so we need to transfer HTTP links to URLs.
I made a function to accomplish this by doing the following: replace `td` with `td/a` can transfer `http` link to `url`.
`replace_function(df.to_html())`

Here's my the function:

```
def td_replace(html):
   list_tdPartial = re.findall('<td>http(.*?)</td>', html, re.S)
   list_tdAll = []
   for td in list_tdPartial:
      td = "http" + td
      list_tdAll.append(td)
   for td in list_tdAll:
      list_link = td.split('<br>')
      list_link_after = []
      for i in range(len(list_link)):
         before = list_link[i]
         after = f'<a href="{before}" target="_blank">{cat}{i + 1}</a>' 
         list_link_after.append(after)
      td_after = '<br>'.join(list_link_after)
      html = html.replace(td, td_after)
   return html
```